# What is the best way to handle this Scam

Tags: discussion

[image: scam]

Just Reject, since there is no Delete option ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Reject" means "Delete the edit" in this case, so yes, "Reject" is the right thing to do.

Comment: Yup, use vandalism as the rejection reason.

Comment: Indeed, this will also "train" the scam detection system to auto-flag such edits better